# How to move folder from one location to another location using java

Tags: java, file, filesystems, filepath

How to move one folder from one location to another location ?
Here is sample code what i did but here it is showing `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException`
I am using this Package: 
`import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;`

```
Path path1 = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("D:\\VFSImagecomp\\compressed\\");
Path path2 = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("D:\\destinitionFile\\");

Files.move(path1, path2, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Here i am trying to move the compressed folder into destinitionFile Folder.But it is not working .Can you Please suggest Me?

Comment: I would try renaming it.

Comment: @manwearraj -  I would use `System.getProperty("path.separator")` to determine the needed `\` automatically so you don't need to guess if it's one or two of them. Just as a side note :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the name of your destination otherwise it will replace your `parent` folder instead (Since you are using `REPLACE_EXISTING`)

```
 Path path1 = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("D:\\VFSImagecomp\\compressed");
 Path path2 = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("D:\\destinitionFile\\myNewDirectory");
```

If you want to keep the same name then:

```
 Path path2 = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("D:\\destinitionFile\\compressed");
```

Comment: Thanks for Reply...now itz working.suppose if run 2nd this application it is showing DirectoryNotEmptyException...But already i placed REPLACE_EXISTING,why it is not working....@gttgaxiola

Comment: [Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/copy.html) states: `REPLACE_EXISTING – Performs the copy even when the target file already exists. If the target is a symbolic link, the link itself is copied (and not the target of the link). If the target is a non-empty directory, the copy fails with the FileAlreadyExistsException exception.`

Comment: Either you rename the destination directory, or have to delete the existing folder prior to the move